# Not receiving fcm on data change in realtime database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-functions

I have written a cloud function to receive fcm whenever there is something change in database but currently it's not working:

```
exports.sendPush = functions.database.ref('/news-6ff9e').onWrite(event => {
let projectStateChanged = false;
let projectCreated = false;
let projectData = event.data.val();
if (!event.data.previous.exists()) {
    projectCreated = true;
}
if (!projectCreated && event.data.changed()) {
    projectStateChanged = true;
}

let msg = 'A project state was changed';

if (projectCreated) {
    msg = `The following new project was added to the project: ${projectData.title}`;
}

let payload = {
    notification: {
        title: 'Firebase Notification',
        body: msg,
        sound: 'default',
        badge: '1'
    }
};

return admin.messaging().sendToTopic("/topics/news", payload);
});
```

`/news-6ff9e` is my project id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using `/news-6ff9e` for my reference which is project id. I have changed this with my database object and issue resolved.